# In a list, how to prevent having a pointer to the container class in all contained items of the list

Tags: list, pointers, architecture

I have two classes : A "Tile" class, which contains a list of Items.
( Example : Tile : Beach / Items : Boat, Seaweed, Seashell )

The Item class has events, which create items in the Tile.
I have a pointer of a Tile in each Items in the Tile's list.
It's needed when the Item changes the Tile's properties ( ex : the Seaweed reproduces and adds another Seaweed to the Beach )

[the pointer of the tile which contains the Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wTXZ.png)

The question is : How to I prevent having a pointer in all of my Items, which points to the tile the item is contained in.

I understand the question might be blurry, but I wonder if there's a common architecture to prevent this type of things.

I tried passing the Tile as a parameter when creating an Item in the tile, to do everything when the Item initializes, but I also need the reference to the Tile after the initialization

Comment: And what exact problem to you have/experience which causes you to want to remove this link?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I'm afraid when i'm gonna serialize the class ( for saving ) or that the instance would take too much memory.

Comment: Usually serializers allow to exclude data from serialization (for example via attributes).

Comment: I'll check of this. Otherwise, doesn't seem like a outstanding thing to do ?

Comment: Without seeing whole codebase it is hard to tell but in general - no.

Comment: thanks a lot then ! i'll clear the thread